# Twitter REST API oauth '215 Bad Authentication data' using fetch in react-native

Tags: rest, twitter, react-native, oauth, fetch

I'm trying to build a react native app to show a user's twitter timeline, but can't manage to access the twitter REST api because I am getting a

> 215 Bad Authentication data

error.

I've signed in the user correctly, gotten all the access tokens, and using fetch to make a request.
I've also verified that all my keys and tokens are correct, yet I still can't manage to figure out why I'm getting this error, my code is available below;

Can anyone please advise me on how to debug this or tell me what's wrong with my code?
thanks.

code:

```
let header = this._buildRequestHeader(twitter_token, twitter_tokenSecret);
    console.log(header);
     fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json', {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
         'Accept': '*/*',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Authorization': ' '+header
       }
     }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log(json);
        })
```

_getBaseString:

```
_getBaseString(method, url, parameter_string){
return method+'&'+
       encodeURIComponent(url)+'&'+encodeURIComponent(parameter_string);
```

}

_getSignature:

```
_getSignature(user_auth_token, accesstoken_secret, data){
// let signing_key = encodeURIComponent(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)+'&'+
//                   encodeURIComponent(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
let signing_key = encodeURIComponent(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)+'&'+
                  encodeURIComponent(accesstoken_secret);
console.log('signing data');
console.log(data);
return this.b64EncodeUnicode(hmacsha1(signing_key, data));
```

}

_buildRequestHeader:

```
_buildRequestHeader(user_auth_token, accesstoken_secret){
// https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures
// https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests
let include_entities_key = encodeURIComponent('include_entities');
let include_entities_val = encodeURIComponent('false');

let oauth_consumer_key_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_consumer_key');
let oauth_consumer_key_val = encodeURIComponent(Constants.TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY);

let oauth_nonce_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_nonce');
let oauth_nonce_val = encodeURIComponent(this._getNonce());

let oauth_signature_method_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature_method');
let oauth_signature_method_val = encodeURIComponent('HMAC-SHA1');

let oauth_timestamp_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_timestamp');
var val = Date.now() / 1000;
console.log(val);
console.log('parse'+parseInt(val));
let oauth_timestamp_val = encodeURIComponent(parseInt(val));

let oauth_token_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_token');
// let oauth_token_val = encodeURIComponent(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN);
let oauth_token_val = encodeURIComponent(user_auth_token);

let oauth_version_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_version');
let oauth_version_val = encodeURIComponent('1.0');

// let parameter_string = include_entities_key+'='+include_entities_val+'&'+
let parameter_string =  oauth_consumer_key_key+'='+oauth_consumer_key_val+'&'+
                    oauth_nonce_key+'='+oauth_nonce_val+'&'+
                    oauth_signature_method_key+'='+oauth_signature_method_val+'&'+
                    oauth_timestamp_key+'='+oauth_timestamp_val+'&'+
                    oauth_token_key+'='+oauth_token_val+'&'+
                    oauth_version_key+'='+oauth_version_val;

let data = this._getBaseString('GET', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json',
              parameter_string);

let signature = this._getSignature(user_auth_token, accesstoken_secret, data)
console.log('signature'+signature);
// 1499887682711
// 1318622958
let oauth_signature_key = encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature');
let oauth_signature_val = encodeURIComponent(signature);

let request_header_string = 'OAuth '+
                    oauth_consumer_key_key+'="'+oauth_consumer_key_val+'", '+
                    oauth_nonce_key+'="'+oauth_nonce_val+'", '+
                    oauth_signature_key+'="'+oauth_signature_val+'", '+
                    oauth_signature_method_key+'="'+oauth_signature_method_val+'", '+
                    oauth_timestamp_key+'="'+oauth_timestamp_val+'", '+
                    oauth_token_key+'="'+oauth_token_val+'", '+
                    oauth_version_key+'="'+oauth_version_val+'"';
return request_header_string;
```

}

But I get a 215 Bad Authentication data. Can someone please advise?

Comment: 'Authorization': ' '+header
Why this empty space before Header?

Comment: I realised that also contributed to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was: The [HMAC-SHA1 function](https://github.com/pH200/hmacsha1-js)I was using was already doing the base-64 encoding for me. 
and as Maciej Adamczewski pointed out, there was an unnecessary whitespace in the header string

Comment: :-) nice to here that I could help